# Is there a way to manipulate content styles, while keeping the border still?

Tags: css, sass, hover

Look at this code for instance, am trying to achieve two things on hover; background change, and moving the content slightly to the right on hover. The border-top should remain intact, and the background should not touch the border-top. When I apply the effects to  `parent > *` the background is separate; covers the first item (icon) and the second (text) independently.

```css
.service-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1.5px solid #dddddd;
  padding:2rem 0.5rem;
}

.service-item .icon {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.service-item .icon svg {
  width: 30px;
}

.service-item .service-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.service-item .service-content h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.service-item .service-content p {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
}

.service-item:hover > * {
  background: #eff1f7;
  transform: translateX(10%)
}
```

```html
<div class="service-item">
  <div class="icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 43 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M42.9998 18.5392C42.9998 16.7393 42.033 15.1846 40.6109 14.3407V2.69626C40.6109 2.02975 40.0898 0.257996 38.222 0.257996C37.6904 0.257996 37.1627 0.439285 36.7304 0.792722L30.3827 5.9747C27.1943 8.5752 23.1914 10.008 19.1109 10.008H4.77753C2.13856 10.008 -0.000244141 12.1903 -0.000244141 14.883V22.1955C-0.000244141 24.8882 2.13856 27.0705 4.77753 27.0705H7.29333C7.18956 27.8688 7.13059 28.6808 7.13059 29.508C7.13059 32.5373 7.82187 35.3999 9.03871 37.9585C9.42616 38.7728 10.272 39.258 11.1589 39.258H16.7041C18.6488 39.258 19.8163 36.985 18.6376 35.4067C17.4133 33.7675 16.6854 31.7231 16.6854 29.508C16.6854 28.6617 16.8063 27.8482 17.0146 27.0705H19.1109C23.1914 27.0705 27.1943 28.5033 30.3819 31.1038L36.7297 36.2858C37.153 36.6315 37.679 36.82 38.2212 36.8205C40.0816 36.8205 40.6101 35.0853 40.6101 34.383V22.7386C42.033 21.8939 42.9998 20.3392 42.9998 18.5392ZM35.8331 29.3115L33.3658 27.2975C29.3346 24.0069 24.2709 22.1955 19.1109 22.1955V14.883C24.2709 14.883 29.3346 13.0716 33.3658 9.781L35.8331 7.76702V29.3115Z"
                    fill="black"
                  />
                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Marketing Brands</h3>
    <p>
      We understand the advertising market as well as the consumers
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="service-item">
  <div class="icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 43 49" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M14.2051 27.5323H10.3658C9.73234 27.5323 9.21404 27.0261 9.21404 26.4073V22.6573C9.21404 22.0386 9.73234 21.5323 10.3658 21.5323H14.2051C14.8386 21.5323 15.3569 22.0386 15.3569 22.6573V26.4073C15.3569 27.0261 14.8386 27.5323 14.2051 27.5323ZM24.5712 26.4073V22.6573C24.5712 22.0386 24.0529 21.5323 23.4194 21.5323H19.5801C18.9466 21.5323 18.4283 22.0386 18.4283 22.6573V26.4073C18.4283 27.0261 18.9466 27.5323 19.5801 27.5323H23.4194C24.0529 27.5323 24.5712 27.0261 24.5712 26.4073ZM33.7855 26.4073V22.6573C33.7855 22.0386 33.2672 21.5323 32.6337 21.5323H28.7944C28.1609 21.5323 27.6426 22.0386 27.6426 22.6573V26.4073C27.6426 27.0261 28.1609 27.5323 28.7944 27.5323H32.6337C33.2672 27.5323 33.7855 27.0261 33.7855 26.4073ZM24.5712 35.4073V31.6573C24.5712 31.0386 24.0529 30.5323 23.4194 30.5323H19.5801C18.9466 30.5323 18.4283 31.0386 18.4283 31.6573V35.4073C18.4283 36.0261 18.9466 36.5323 19.5801 36.5323H23.4194C24.0529 36.5323 24.5712 36.0261 24.5712 35.4073ZM15.3569 35.4073V31.6573C15.3569 31.0386 14.8386 30.5323 14.2051 30.5323H10.3658C9.73234 30.5323 9.21404 31.0386 9.21404 31.6573V35.4073C9.21404 36.0261 9.73234 36.5323 10.3658 36.5323H14.2051C14.8386 36.5323 15.3569 36.0261 15.3569 35.4073ZM33.7855 35.4073V31.6573C33.7855 31.0386 33.2672 30.5323 32.6337 30.5323H28.7944C28.1609 30.5323 27.6426 31.0386 27.6426 31.6573V35.4073C27.6426 36.0261 28.1609 36.5323 28.7944 36.5323H32.6337C33.2672 36.5323 33.7855 36.0261 33.7855 35.4073ZM42.9998 11.0323V44.0323C42.9998 46.5167 40.9361 48.5323 38.3926 48.5323H4.6069C2.06337 48.5323 -0.000244141 46.5167 -0.000244141 44.0323V11.0323C-0.000244141 8.54797 2.06337 6.53235 4.6069 6.53235H9.21404V1.65735C9.21404 1.0386 9.73234 0.532349 10.3658 0.532349H14.2051C14.8386 0.532349 15.3569 1.0386 15.3569 1.65735V6.53235H27.6426V1.65735C27.6426 1.0386 28.1609 0.532349 28.7944 0.532349H32.6337C33.2672 0.532349 33.7855 1.0386 33.7855 1.65735V6.53235H38.3926C40.9361 6.53235 42.9998 8.54797 42.9998 11.0323ZM38.3926 43.4698V15.5323H4.6069V43.4698C4.6069 43.7792 4.86605 44.0323 5.18279 44.0323H37.8167C38.1335 44.0323 38.3926 43.7792 38.3926 43.4698Z"
                    fill="black"
                  />
                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Events Management</h3>
    <p>
      We have managed numerous campaigns and product activations for over 20 years
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! It is still unclear what you are looking for. Maybe if possible post a screenshot of expected behavior on hover.

Comment: I dont have a screenshot. If you run the code snippet, you'll notice that on hover, the background is not continuous. instead the icon and text each has independent backgrounds. I want it continuous

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this is what you are trying to achieve.  I separated the background color being added on hover into another section which will cover the whole div, and another section for the section which is to move to the right.

EDIT: I updated code.

```
.service-item:hover > .service-content {
  transform: translateX(10%)
}

.service-item:hover {
  background: #eff1f7;
}
```

Here is a working example:

```css
.service-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1.5px solid #dddddd;
  padding:2rem 0.5rem;
}

.service-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.service-item .icon {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.service-item .icon svg {
  width: 30px;
}

.service-item .service-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.service-item .service-content h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.service-item .service-content p {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
}

.service-item:hover {
  padding-left: 10%
}

.service-item:hover  {
  background: #eff1f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-wrap">
<div class="service-item">

  <div class="icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 43 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M42.9998 18.5392C42.9998 16.7393 42.033 15.1846 40.6109 14.3407V2.69626C40.6109 2.02975 40.0898 0.257996 38.222 0.257996C37.6904 0.257996 37.1627 0.439285 36.7304 0.792722L30.3827 5.9747C27.1943 8.5752 23.1914 10.008 19.1109 10.008H4.77753C2.13856 10.008 -0.000244141 12.1903 -0.000244141 14.883V22.1955C-0.000244141 24.8882 2.13856 27.0705 4.77753 27.0705H7.29333C7.18956 27.8688 7.13059 28.6808 7.13059 29.508C7.13059 32.5373 7.82187 35.3999 9.03871 37.9585C9.42616 38.7728 10.272 39.258 11.1589 39.258H16.7041C18.6488 39.258 19.8163 36.985 18.6376 35.4067C17.4133 33.7675 16.6854 31.7231 16.6854 29.508C16.6854 28.6617 16.8063 27.8482 17.0146 27.0705H19.1109C23.1914 27.0705 27.1943 28.5033 30.3819 31.1038L36.7297 36.2858C37.153 36.6315 37.679 36.82 38.2212 36.8205C40.0816 36.8205 40.6101 35.0853 40.6101 34.383V22.7386C42.033 21.8939 42.9998 20.3392 42.9998 18.5392ZM35.8331 29.3115L33.3658 27.2975C29.3346 24.0069 24.2709 22.1955 19.1109 22.1955V14.883C24.2709 14.883 29.3346 13.0716 33.3658 9.781L35.8331 7.76702V29.3115Z"
                    fill="black"
                  />
                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Marketing Brands</h3>
    <p>
      We understand the advertising market as well as the consumers
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="service-wrap">
<div class="service-item">
  <div class="icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 43 49" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M14.2051 27.5323H10.3658C9.73234 27.5323 9.21404 27.0261 9.21404 26.4073V22.6573C9.21404 22.0386 9.73234 21.5323 10.3658 21.5323H14.2051C14.8386 21.5323 15.3569 22.0386 15.3569 22.6573V26.4073C15.3569 27.0261 14.8386 27.5323 14.2051 27.5323ZM24.5712 26.4073V22.6573C24.5712 22.0386 24.0529 21.5323 23.4194 21.5323H19.5801C18.9466 21.5323 18.4283 22.0386 18.4283 22.6573V26.4073C18.4283 27.0261 18.9466 27.5323 19.5801 27.5323H23.4194C24.0529 27.5323 24.5712 27.0261 24.5712 26.4073ZM33.7855 26.4073V22.6573C33.7855 22.0386 33.2672 21.5323 32.6337 21.5323H28.7944C28.1609 21.5323 27.6426 22.0386 27.6426 22.6573V26.4073C27.6426 27.0261 28.1609 27.5323 28.7944 27.5323H32.6337C33.2672 27.5323 33.7855 27.0261 33.7855 26.4073ZM24.5712 35.4073V31.6573C24.5712 31.0386 24.0529 30.5323 23.4194 30.5323H19.5801C18.9466 30.5323 18.4283 31.0386 18.4283 31.6573V35.4073C18.4283 36.0261 18.9466 36.5323 19.5801 36.5323H23.4194C24.0529 36.5323 24.5712 36.0261 24.5712 35.4073ZM15.3569 35.4073V31.6573C15.3569 31.0386 14.8386 30.5323 14.2051 30.5323H10.3658C9.73234 30.5323 9.21404 31.0386 9.21404 31.6573V35.4073C9.21404 36.0261 9.73234 36.5323 10.3658 36.5323H14.2051C14.8386 36.5323 15.3569 36.0261 15.3569 35.4073ZM33.7855 35.4073V31.6573C33.7855 31.0386 33.2672 30.5323 32.6337 30.5323H28.7944C28.1609 30.5323 27.6426 31.0386 27.6426 31.6573V35.4073C27.6426 36.0261 28.1609 36.5323 28.7944 36.5323H32.6337C33.2672 36.5323 33.7855 36.0261 33.7855 35.4073ZM42.9998 11.0323V44.0323C42.9998 46.5167 40.9361 48.5323 38.3926 48.5323H4.6069C2.06337 48.5323 -0.000244141 46.5167 -0.000244141 44.0323V11.0323C-0.000244141 8.54797 2.06337 6.53235 4.6069 6.53235H9.21404V1.65735C9.21404 1.0386 9.73234 0.532349 10.3658 0.532349H14.2051C14.8386 0.532349 15.3569 1.0386 15.3569 1.65735V6.53235H27.6426V1.65735C27.6426 1.0386 28.1609 0.532349 28.7944 0.532349H32.6337C33.2672 0.532349 33.7855 1.0386 33.7855 1.65735V6.53235H38.3926C40.9361 6.53235 42.9998 8.54797 42.9998 11.0323ZM38.3926 43.4698V15.5323H4.6069V43.4698C4.6069 43.7792 4.86605 44.0323 5.18279 44.0323H37.8167C38.1335 44.0323 38.3926 43.7792 38.3926 43.4698Z"
                    fill="black"
                  />
                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Events Management</h3>
    <p>
      We have managed numerous campaigns and product activations for over 20 years
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

:

Comment: Thank you @john The icon should however move with the content on hover as well, and the background should not touch the border-top.

Comment: @Sags I've updated my answer to address this.  I've created a wrapper div over each `service-item` and used  `padding-left: 10%` instead of translate to achieve what you are looking to do.

Comment: That is the behaviour am looking for. But is there no way to achieve this without changing the html?

Comment: @Sags this would be the best I can do without altering the HTML at all: https://jsfiddle.net/y9pjx82s/

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not want the content div to touch your border. I have made slight changes in HTML and applied CSS that solves your problem.

```css
.service-item-wrapper{
  border-top:5px solid green;
  padding:1rem 0;
  
}
.service-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height:200px;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.service-item .icon {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.service-item .icon svg {
  width: 30px;
}

.service-item .service-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.service-item .service-content h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.service-item .service-content p {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
}
.service-item-wrapper:hover  .service-item{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: teal;
  margin-left:10%;
} 



/*  there are no accidents  */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="service-item-wrapper">
  <div class="service-item">
  <div class="icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 43 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M42.9998 18.5392C42.9998 16.7393 42.033 15.1846 40.6109 14.3407V2.69626C40.6109 2.02975 40.0898 0.257996 38.222 0.257996C37.6904 0.257996 37.1627 0.439285 36.7304 0.792722L30.3827 5.9747C27.1943 8.5752 23.1914 10.008 19.1109 10.008H4.77753C2.13856 10.008 -0.000244141 12.1903 -0.000244141 14.883V22.1955C-0.000244141 24.8882 2.13856 27.0705 4.77753 27.0705H7.29333C7.18956 27.8688 7.13059 28.6808 7.13059 29.508C7.13059 32.5373 7.82187 35.3999 9.03871 37.9585C9.42616 38.7728 10.272 39.258 11.1589 39.258H16.7041C18.6488 39.258 19.8163 36.985 18.6376 35.4067C17.4133 33.7675 16.6854 31.7231 16.6854 29.508C16.6854 28.6617 16.8063 27.8482 17.0146 27.0705H19.1109C23.1914 27.0705 27.1943 28.5033 30.3819 31.1038L36.7297 36.2858C37.153 36.6315 37.679 36.82 38.2212 36.8205C40.0816 36.8205 40.6101 35.0853 40.6101 34.383V22.7386C42.033 21.8939 42.9998 20.3392 42.9998 18.5392ZM35.8331 29.3115L33.3658 27.2975C29.3346 24.0069 24.2709 22.1955 19.1109 22.1955V14.883C24.2709 14.883 29.3346 13.0716 33.3658 9.781L35.8331 7.76702V29.3115Z"
                    fill="black"
                  />
                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Marketing Brands</h3>
    <p>
      We understand the advertising market as well as the consumers
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
  </section>

  <section class="service-item-wrapper">
  <div class="service-item">
  <div class="icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 43 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M42.9998 18.5392C42.9998 16.7393 42.033 15.1846 40.6109 14.3407V2.69626C40.6109 2.02975 40.0898 0.257996 38.222 0.257996C37.6904 0.257996 37.1627 0.439285 36.7304 0.792722L30.3827 5.9747C27.1943 8.5752 23.1914 10.008 19.1109 10.008H4.77753C2.13856 10.008 -0.000244141 12.1903 -0.000244141 14.883V22.1955C-0.000244141 24.8882 2.13856 27.0705 4.77753 27.0705H7.29333C7.18956 27.8688 7.13059 28.6808 7.13059 29.508C7.13059 32.5373 7.82187 35.3999 9.03871 37.9585C9.42616 38.7728 10.272 39.258 11.1589 39.258H16.7041C18.6488 39.258 19.8163 36.985 18.6376 35.4067C17.4133 33.7675 16.6854 31.7231 16.6854 29.508C16.6854 28.6617 16.8063 27.8482 17.0146 27.0705H19.1109C23.1914 27.0705 27.1943 28.5033 30.3819 31.1038L36.7297 36.2858C37.153 36.6315 37.679 36.82 38.2212 36.8205C40.0816 36.8205 40.6101 35.0853 40.6101 34.383V22.7386C42.033 21.8939 42.9998 20.3392 42.9998 18.5392ZM35.8331 29.3115L33.3658 27.2975C29.3346 24.0069 24.2709 22.1955 19.1109 22.1955V14.883C24.2709 14.883 29.3346 13.0716 33.3658 9.781L35.8331 7.76702V29.3115Z"
                    fill="black"
                  />
                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Marketing Brands</h3>
    <p>
      We understand the advertising market as well as the consumers
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sags: Do let me know if it solves your problem :) Happy Coding

Comment: is there totaly no way to do it without introducing new html elements?

Comment: Why not there are always many ways to solve a problem. But right now I am occupied dear @Sags. If I get time in latter part of the day, will do it for you Insha Allah :) U also keep trying till then